# java string to char array recognising spaces

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to write some java whereby a string is passed into a char array, at the minute I've got that bit working fine, however I now need to increase the capability so the array is able to recognize the spaces within the original String and output them into the array or  change them into '-' so that the output of the code will have the spaces visible.

```java
private static char[] checkForJ(String encodeInput){
        StringBuilder tempString = new StringBuilder();

        encodeInput = encodeInput.toLowerCase();
        char[] ch  = encodeInput.toCharArray();
        for(char x : ch){
            if(x == ' '){

                x = '-';
                tempString.append(x);
            }
            if(x == 'j'){
                x = 'i';
                tempString.append(x);
            }else {
                tempString.append(x);
            }
        }
        String finalString = tempString.toString();
        char[] newChar = finalString.toCharArray();
        return newChar;
```

The String is passed into the method externally and it then outputs the array for more processing.

Input being: abc def ghi jkl

Expected output: abc-def-ghi-ikl

Actual Output: abcdefghiikl

Comment: Well currently you're appending `-` *twice* for every space. Is that the problem that you're facing? It's hard to tell - you haven't given an example of input/expected output/actual output. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `return encodeInput.replace(' ','-').replace('j','i').toCharArray();`

Comment: @4castle `replaceAll`

Comment: @Zircon `replaceAll` is for if you used a regex.

Comment: @Zircon replaceAll is intended for use with a regex it has nothing to do with how many values are changed.

Comment: @4castle I would personally use character literals in place of `String`s but it shouldn't be a big deal

Comment: Currently I am looking for:

Comment: input: abc def ghi jkl output: abc def ghi ikl,

Comment: but currently getting output of: abcdefghiikl

Comment: @JonSkeet I have tried your example, and it works beautifully, many thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to provide more details, and provide a [mcve]. It's entirely possible the problem is in what you're doing with the result, for example.

Comment: (I'm not sure what you mean by "I have tried your example" - I didn't provide an example. Did you mean 4castle?)

Comment: Yes I apologise i meant @4castle,

Comment: To update your question use [edit] option (placed below tags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small change fixes it: Add `else` before the second `if`:

```
private static char[] checkForJ(String encodeInput){
    StringBuilder tempString = new StringBuilder();
    encodeInput = encodeInput.toLowerCase();
    char[] ch  = encodeInput.toCharArray();
    for(char x : ch){
        if(x == ' '){
            x = '-';
            tempString.append(x);
        }else if(x == 'j'){
            x = 'i';
            tempString.append(x);
        }else {
            tempString.append(x);
        }
    }
    String finalString = tempString.toString();
    char[] newChar = finalString.toCharArray();
    return newChar;
}
```

However, this is quite wordy. It can be done all at once with:

```
private static char[] checkForJ(String encodeInput){
    return encodeInput.toLowerCase()
                      .replace(' ','-')
                      .replace('j','i')
                      .toCharArray();
}
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/87WDnp)

Comment: Many Thanks, I have now completed this section, and much happier with the results.

Comment: Since `tempString.append(x);` is executed in both if/else cases there is no point in having `else` if it is its only instruction. Simply invoke it after `if`. Also `if(x == 'j')` should most probably be `else if(x == 'j')` to avoid scenarios where we will change space to `j` and then again test if `x` is `j` and replace it with `i`.

Comment: @Pshemo That makes much more sense. I've updated. I'm going to refrain from adding more efficiencies though because they should be using the one-liner anyway.

Comment: Okay so I broke this again. @4castle, using the line: System.out.println("checkJ " + encodeOutput); I get output of "checkJ [C@1540e19d" with an input string of "hello world" yet if I remove the ("checkJ " + ) it returns "hello-world".  Any ideas?

Comment: @DavidPinchen there are few `println` methods. One of them is `println(char[] array)` and other is `print(Object)`. When you call `print("foo"+someCharArray)` then compiler see it as `print("foo"+someCharArray.toString())` so it first will invoke `toString` from array (which will create `[C@1540e19d` since this is implementation which each array inherits from Object) and then it will concatenate it with `foo` and print result. If you invoke `print(someCharArray)` then instead of `println(Object)` `println(char[] array)` will be invoked which simply prints each character in array.

Comment: @DavidPinchen `System.out.println` is overloaded to print `char[]`, but Strings are not overloaded to be able to concatenate with `char[]`. It's probable that you don't even need `encodeOutput` to be an array. A string could be sufficient.

Comment: @DavidPinchen Try with `System.out.println("checkJ " + new String(encodeOutput));` and you should be fine.

Comment: @Pshemo I am conversing with a friend as well, and he came up with the same  solution, which has proved successful, many thanks.